# argument of a lacunary sum of roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $q>4$ and $t< \sqrt{q}$ be integers. Determine the set $\{j_1,...,j_t\}$ of integers $0 \leq j_i <q-1$ such that $\arg(\sum_{i=0}^t e^{2i\pi\frac{j_i}{q}} ) \in [0,\pi[$.

Comment: "The" set? There will generally be many possible solutions -- for example any choice where every $j_i$ is less than $q/2$.

Comment: I want to determine all solutions

Comment: You may be asking for too much. Have you worked out any examples, to get a feel for what's going on?